# What does it mean for literature to be “reflective”?

Tags: terminology, style

The book-review and -recommendation site *The Storygraph* allows users to categorise books in various ways such as *adventurous, funny, inspiring,* and *reflective.* Some (fiction) books I know have been judged to be reflective by many reviewers while others not at all, so there seems to be some agreement on the meaning of this. However, I fail to see what distinguishes these books, and thus I ask: When is literature categorised as *reflective?*

I can think at least of the following interpretations, at least some of which are clearly distinct:

- The author discusses the events of the story on page, i.e., the book is the product of [reflective writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_writing).
- The characters (or the third-person narrator) discuss the events of the story.
- The story holds up the mirror to the reader.
- The author explores real-world questions or events by means of telling a story.

Any reasonable Internet search I could come up with yielded primarily information on reflective writing or reflections on literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [asked](https://twitter.com/RabelaisA11y/status/1385974698299777024) @thestorygraph on Twittter:

> What exactly are the criteria for the tag/mood "reflective" on [@thestorygraph](https://twitter.com/thestorygraph)?
> Or should I ask [@nodunayo](https://twitter.com/nodunayo) and [@RobFrelow](https://twitter.com/RobFrelow) ?

(Nadia Odunayo and Rob Frelow are co-founders of The Storygraph.)

This was the [answer](https://twitter.com/thestorygraph/status/1385992026945204228):

> There is no set criteria for it! Typically a book that is thought-provoking, deliberative, references past memories, etc., would have that tag!

"Reflective mood" is otherwise not known to me as a specific literary term. For example, it is not defined in *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms* by Chris Baldick (Oxford University Press, 2001). That doesn't mean Baldick doesn't use the term, but two of the three occurrences of the term are related to Horace; for example:

> The Horatian ode, as distinct from the Pindaric ode, is homostrophic
> and usually private and reflective in mood: Keats's odes (1820) are
> English examples of this form.